# '01 Lexus IS200, do I need a new fuel filter?

Tags: fuel-system, lexus, fuel-filter

My 2001 Lexus IS200 is about to hit 100 thousand km and I am about to change the oil, oil filter, air and cabin filters. My question is, do I need a new fuel filter this early in the life of the car? It's been using Spanish gas all its life which is not the worst out there, I guess. I have tried to find Lexus recommendations on it but to no avail. Any hints? Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The fuel filter on your vehicle is part of its fuel pump in the fuel tank. They are designed and made to last the 'life of the vehicle'. They have a plastic OBD2 fuel tank with an interior 'bladder', which means unless something other then normal operation causes damage they never have to be changed.

Comment: What do you mean by bladder - does it self clean? If so where does it throws all the junk from fuel?

Answer (score 2):

If it's never been changed, then yes, I'd change it. To get 100k out of a fuel filter is a good life for it. Fuel filters are usually not too expensive, so are a decent maintenance item to take care of. They are also usually fairly easy to change ... usually.